# How to Properly Put together a Function in Powershell

Tags: powershell, session, powershell-remoting

I have done a ton of research on how to push this EXE to a remote PC using `PSSession` and all lines of code work when executed line by line. But i have had a hard time putting this into a function that makes sense and will execute all lines of code and successfully install the software with one push of a button. Not sure whats happening. It will install the exe locally when i tried to do put all lines of code in a function and run it. Can you please help instruct what i am doing wrong? Sorry i am a newbie at Powershell.

```
  $dc1 = New-PSSession -ComputerName DC1
  Copy-Item C:\TPAdmin\Greenshot-INSTALLER-1.2.10.6-RELEASE.exe -Destination C:\TPAdmin -ToSession $dc1
  Enter-PSSession -Session $dc1
  Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {C:\TPAdmin\Greenshot-INSTALLER-1.2.10.6-RELEASE.exe /VERYSILENT /LOG="C:\SOFTWAREINSTALL.LOG" 
 Remove-Pssession $dc1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`Enter-PSSession` is for *interactive* use only**, so not suitable for use in a *function*.<sup>[1]</sup>

Instead of using `Enter-PSSession`, **pass the session you've created with `New-Session` to the `Invoke-Command` command's `-Session` parameter**, which will run the command in the context of that (remote) session.

```
# Define your function...
function Invoke-InstallerRemotely {
  param([string] $ComputerName)
  $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ComputerName
  Copy-Item C:\TPAdmin\Greenshot-INSTALLER-1.2.10.6-RELEASE.exe -Destination C:\TPAdmin -ToSession $session
  # Do NOT use Enter-PSSession.
  # Pass your session to Invoke-Command with -Session
  Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {C:\TPAdmin\Greenshot-INSTALLER-1.2.10.6-RELEASE.exe /VERYSILENT /LOG="C:\SOFTWAREINSTALL.LOG" 
  Remove-PSSession $session
}

# ... then invoke it.
# Note that functions must be defined *before* they're called.
Invoke-InstallerRemotely -ComputerName DC1
```

---

<sup>[1] Using it in a function means that an *interactive session* on the target computer is entered, which you must *exit* interactively (by typing and submitting `exit` or `Exit-PSSession`) before the remaining statements in the function are executed, again *locally*.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

As for …

> Sorry i am a newbie at Powershell.

… that's all fine, as we all had to start from somewhere. However... a couple of things here:

- Please be sure to format your posts, to encourage folks to want to
  help. People frown on no doing that. Having to copy, paste and
  reformat your post is well, extra unnecessary work.  ***;-}***. We've al been there.
- We have no idea how you are getting up to speed on PowerShell, but
  use the freely available resources to limit/avoid all the
  misconceptions, frustrations, errors, potential bad habits, etc.,
  that you are going to encounter. Live on watching the videos on:
- [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=beginning%20powershell%20)
- [Microsoft Virtual Academy](https://mva.microsoft.com/search/SearchResults.aspx#!q=powershell&lang=1033)
- [MSDN Channel9](https://channel9.msdn.com/Search?term=powershell&lang-en=true)
- [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/)
- as well as the [reference](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/183.windows-powershell-survival-guide.aspx)
- and [eBook](https://powertheshell.com/cookbooks) resources.

Back to your use case. You do not say what is happening. So, you leave us to guess. Which is not really potentially helpful to you.

Nonetheless, you should just need to do this... in PowerShell v5x as it's require to use the -ToSession argument.

```
$DC1 = New-PSSession -ComputerName 'DC1'
Copy-Item -ToSession $DC1 -Path 'C:\TPAdmin\Greenshot-INSTALLER-1.2.10.6-RELEASE.exe' -Destination 'C:\TPAdmin'
Invoke-Command -Session $DC1 -ScriptBlock {C:\TPAdmin\Greenshot-INSTALLER-1.2.10.6-RELEASE.exe /VERYSILENT /LOG="C:\SOFTWAREINSTALL.LOG"}
Remove-PSSession -Session $DC1
```

I am not sure why you are doing that [Enter-PSSsssion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enter-pssession) in the [New-PSSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssession) command as it is not needed. It's for standalone interactive sessions.

[Explicit PSRemoting = Enter=PSSEssion](https://blog.netspi.com/powershell-remoting-cheatsheet/)

[Implicit PSREmoting = New-PSSEssion](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/remoting-the-implicit-way/)

If all else fails for you on the copy via the session, then just use the normal UNC way to copy from source to destination.

```
Copy-Item -Path 'C:\temp\Results.csv' -Destination "\\$($DC1.Computername)\c$\temp"
```

See also:
[Copy To or From a PowerShell Session](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/poshchap/2015/10/30/copy-to-or-from-a-powershell-session/)